# printing from client side client side landscape (ie only)

Tags: asp.net, html, activexobject

Can someone please help with the following: I am trying to force an asp.net page to go in landscape mode and remove all headers and footers.... N.b all clients only uses ie browser. therefore an activex control may work but i have not found any thus far.. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are IE specific you can use CSS to rotate content 90 degrees. [Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb554293%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(Rotation=3);
```

I don't believe there is a JS solution to altering browser settings as this would be a security issue.  ActiveX or some other binary should have access but then you will have installation issues.

Comment: That does not print correctly. I am using sendkeys. And restricting the user agent to ie based browser.